# Why is my boostrap nav bar not going horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For example in: https://codepen.io/SimpleRoger/pen/OmRKNq
The nav bar is vertical not horizontal; please help.

```
<html>
```

Comment: Please don't ignore or bypass the warnings that the editor gives you. Off-site examples, via Codepen or similar, are welcome, but only as additional details. The most relevant snippets from your code need to be included within the question's text.

Comment: Codepen expects the "HTML" editor to only contain the contents of the `<body>`, not a full document. It's trying to include the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` elements for you, so the results end up with two of each element, which wrecks the document. To add external CSS and JS files, use the gear icons at the top of the editor panels. Modified pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNqZrO

Comment: Thanks mate so it was codepen

Answer (score 0):

try run these code please

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Inverted Navbar</h3>
  <p>An inverted navbar is black instead of gray.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Bootstrap is a responsive site framework (sorry i don't know to call it, all i know is that bootstrap generate a responsive websites). So it will automatically detect how long is the height, width the browser displaying the websites. if the display height and width is this much bootstrap will display a web page like this, if the display height and width is that much bootstrap will display the web page like that. Basically bootstrap have 3 display mode that is desktop, tablet and phone, that means bootstrap have 3 different style for 3 different display mode. So if you use codepen i think bootstrap is assuming you're not using desktop so it is displaying the navbar vertically (tablet or phone) like the code I've given above. I've tried to copy and paste your code to my local computer and it runs well (navbar is displayed horizontally). So if you want to make a websites and work with bootstrap I recommend you to work with your local pc, not in codepen. You can copy bootstrap to your local pc, and cou can work with phpStorm or other software like that, that provide easy site upload via ftp to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Your nav bar is working fine in large screen. But in medium and small screen, it gets vertical. So i come up with a easy solution: float the elements to the left. Just add the following code to your style sheet.

```
.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav {
    float: left !important;
}
```

i hope this helps!